# Photoshop Scripting - Place image

Tags: photoshop-script

I need a method of placing a smaller image onto a bigger one in a specific place. Doing this over and over again is tedious. I need a script to do this for me since for some reason or other image placeholders aren't (as far as I know) built into photoshop

Thanks

Comment: I need an example of placing an image in JS for PS. I presumed it would be like two lines

Comment: SO generally expects a certainly level of investigation before questions are asked http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and it would take most users here quite a bit of investigation to help you. As it stands your question is very low quality and doesn't show any effort on your part. You'll get much more success if you read the documentation http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html make an attempt and come back with any questions